# Undefined reference to SDL functions in c for Conways Game of Life

Tags: linux, c, gnu, development, cmake

I'm writing GameOfLife game in c with SDL2 but while compiling the files with CMake, it appears as an undefined reference to SDL functions:

[image]

What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(GameOfLife)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu99 -lrt -lpthread -lSDL2")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.c game.c func.h)

add_executable(GameOfLife ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(GameOfLife SDL2 SDL2main SDL2test glew32 glew32s ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

*Ps I'm new in those development technics*

edit: I'm using Ubuntu OS

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text); rather copy-and-paste them into your question body using appropriate formatting. Also, this question is very much about programming and may be better asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: You might try the recipe here, using `find_package`: [Using SDL2 with CMake](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/)